# Meaning of 前以上?

Tags: meaning, words, syntax

I'm confused about something I've read;

> 前以上のスピードで前以上のクオリティでって、思っちゃうのは思っちゃうんですけど。

Is the 前以上 in the above line supposed to mean "more speed than before, more quality than before" or is it saying "quality comes before speed"?

If someone could explain how the word is affecting that sentence that would be great, I'd really love to know what the speaker is saying here, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

前以上 is "greater than before" and the structure of (verb)のは(verb) means that something is not more than what it is but you have to admit that it's the case anyway if you are asked.

In this case, the speaker admits that s/he certainly thinks that way though s/he is conscious that it's not necessarily reasonable.

All in all, the example sentence means "I can't help wishing (we could do it) with greater speed or with greater quality, though".

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it can be rephrased (hoping it helps.) ;)

> 前以上のスピードで前以上のクオリティでって、思っちゃうのは思っちゃうんですけど。

→前よりも早く、前よりも上手にって、（そんな風に）思っちゃうのは思っちゃうんですけど（なかなか難しいです。 or うまく行きませんでした。, etc.）

Also,

> 前以上のスピードで前以上のクオリティでって、

which means "faster than before *and* better (quality) than before"

If it were "faster *or* better than before", then it might be either,

- 前以上のスピードでとか、前以上のクオリティでって、or
- 前以上のスピードか前以上のクオリティでって、

Basically, just wanted to point out that the speaker wanted to do it (whatever it is) faster and better, not necessarily faster or better.

Answer (score 0):

> "more speed than before, more quality than before"

This translation is correct.

前以上のスピードで前以上のクオリティ
faster than before and better than before

思っちゃうの(/に)は思っちゃうんですけど。 ／ 思ってしまうと言えば思ってしまう。

思ってしまうと言えば思ってしまう(けど) is something like "I expect(/hope) that (they will offer something that is faster and better than the earlier version, product, etc.) if you ask me."

This けど literally means "though" but it actually is nothing more than a copula or "it is (that)".